# Ubuntu 20.04 problems with Chrome, Teams, Visual Studio Code... Maybe related with /dev/shm

Tags: ubuntu, tmpfs

I'm facing fatal errors since 2 weeks in my Ubuntu 20.04. Suddenly, my Chrome, my Visual Studio Code and my Teams app, stop working. They freeze, and I must restart my computer. This happens approximately every 3 hours working without problems.

I see errors in /var/log/syslog, and I found some errors like these:

```
Jun 11 10:40:18 PT114 gnome-shell[4953]: [28752:1:0611/104018.216550:ERROR:broker_posix.cc(46)] Received unexpected number of handles
Jun 11 10:40:18 PT114 gnome-shell[4953]: [5003:5006:0611/104018.421902:ERROR:broker_posix.cc(46)] Received unexpected number of handles
Jun 11 10:40:18 PT114 gnome-shell[4953]: [5003:5006:0611/104018.422351:ERROR:broker_posix.cc(46)] Received unexpected number of handles
...
Jun 11 10:40:21 PT114 gnome-shell[4953]: [4945:4945:0611/104021.716798:ERROR:command_buffer_proxy_impl.cc(92)] ContextResult::kFatalFailure: AllocateAndMapSharedMemory failed
...
Jun 11 10:40:21 PT114 gnome-shell[4953]: --2021-06-11 10:40:21--  https://clients2.google.com/cr/report
Jun 11 10:40:21 PT114 kernel: [ 9638.972965] traps: Compositor[5504] trap invalid opcode ip:5613af8c3d3f sp:7f727d40e480 error:0 in chrome[5613ab4d0000+7f7d000]
...
```

Searching in Google, I found that maybe it's caused by **/dev/shm** mounting point. I execute **df -h** and I see the it was full 100%

```
S.ficheros                  Tamaño Usados  Disp Uso% Montado en
udev                           16G      0   16G   0% /dev
tmpfs                         3,1G   5,1M  3,1G   1% /run
/dev/mapper/vgslimbook-root   456G   348G   85G  81% /
tmpfs                          16G    16G     0 100% /dev/shm
```

I did't made any change related with this drive. In my /etc/fstab file there is no entry related to it.

It seems that this drive is always increasing without never removing it's content. Is there any way to force that this drive never get full?

My computer has 32GB of RAM memory. I think that this size of 16GB was given automatically by Ubuntu during the installation.

The **uname -a** command line output is:

```
Linux PT114 5.10.0-1029-oem #30-Ubuntu SMP Fri May 28 23:53:50 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

And the **lsb_release -a** output is:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
```

Any idea about how to solve it?

Comment: `/dev/shm` is shared memory - not actual disk-type files.

Indeed the "AllocateAndMapSharedMemory failed" error would indicate that some process is not releasing shared memory when it should do.

Typically, you should only expect to see a few % of your 16GB used, at least in a desktop environment.

Close selected applications when shared memory usage starts to become high, in an effort to identify the problem.

Comment: I was doing some tests, closing a lot of processes, but the shm shared memory never decreases from the 100%. I suspect that Chome is the guilty, but I closed all the related proceses without result... Once shared memory is full, Chome, Visual Studio and Teams app doesn't work anymore. Not even reopening these applications. Only restarting the computer solves the problem...

Comment: I resolved the problem by updating the Kernel. Now I have 5.12.10 version, and it works perfectly ;) Maybe it was a problem with 5.10.0-1029-oem kernel version...

Comment: I suggest that you write that up as an answer to your question.

Comment: I have the same problem with Linux 5.11.0-36-generic and Chrome 95.0.4638.17. That's beta Chrome, but Chrome stable had the same problem.  Workaround was to use `--disable-dev-shm-usage` but that then writes to disk, and eventually the disk fills.

Answer (score 1):

The solution I found is to update the Kernel to the latest version. With the version "5.12.10-051210-generic" works perfect again. I used this program to upgrade the Kernel version: Mainline
https://github.com/bkw777/mainline

Answer (score 0):

It is back for me with:

linux-image-generic-hwe-20.04:
Installed: 5.15.0.69.76~20.04.30
google-chrome-stable:
Installed: 112.0.5615.165-1
code:
Installed: 1.77.3-1681292746

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).